# Images disapearing in ListView when deleting an Item

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I am currently working on a Xamarin CrossPlatform project and have implemented a Listview bound to an ObservableCollection. Everything works out fine until I remove an Item from the ListView. The images in the follow up items within the ListView disappear randomly - not all of them and a different amount of them every time. I guess it has something to do with the MemoryStream, but what do I have to change? Here´s the relevant part of my Model that is bound to the ListView:

```
    public string ImageBase64
    {
        get
        {
            return imagebase64;
        }
        set
        {
            if (imagebase64 != value)
            {
                imagebase64 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageBase64));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageSource));
            }
        }
    }

    public ImageSource ImageSource
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagebase64))
            {
                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(imagebase64)));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here´s the relevant XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemSelected="OnListItemSelected" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorColor="{StaticResource primaryGreen}" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Margin="0,5,0,5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="65" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="-2,-2,-2,-2" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" Aspect="AspectFill"/> <!-- This is the displayed Image -->
                    <Label Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" TextColor="{StaticResource primaryGreen}" Text="{Binding VorNachname}" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                    <Label Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MediumSelected.Wert, StringFormat='via {0}'}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                    <StackLayout Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label  Text="{Binding Alter,StringFormat='Alter: {0}'}" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Margin="0,0,0,-5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End">
                        <Button WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White" BorderWidth="0" BorderColor="White" Image="socialmedia_18.png" Clicked="OnChangeClicked" CommandParameter ="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                        <Button Margin="0,-15,0,0" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" BackgroundColor="White" BorderColor="White" Image="cancel_18.png" Clicked="OnDeleteClicked" CommandParameter ="{Binding}" VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

...and the Code behind:

```
    async void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.TrackEvent("PeopleList_OnDeleteClicked");
        //Get selected Person
        Person person = (Person)((Button)sender).CommandParameter;

        //Remove from Model
        DBHelper.DBModel.People.Remove(person);

        //Update database
        App.Database.UpdateWithChildren(DBHelper.DBModel);
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Resizing the images does not help, same problem. I tried it by binding a testvariable ImageSourceThumb to the ListViewItemImage:

```
    public ImageSource ImageSourceThumb
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagebase64))
            {
                return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(ImageResizer.ResizeImage(Convert.FromBase64String(imagebase64), 64, 64)));
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When I loaded or updated my listview not all the images showed up.

I fixed my problem resizing the images. Huge images gived me a outofmemory exception. Resizing those images to a smaller resolution fixed these problems.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried it out and it doesn´t solve the problem. Any other suggestions?